# How to prevent f:selectItems from displaying empty rows?

Tags: jsf

I have 2 database tables that are related to each other;

> Employee and Contact

I want to create a dropdown menu for Employee, and display Employee's first name and last name which are a column in the Contact table.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="employeeDropdown" value="#{employeeController.activeEmployee}">
       <s:selectItems id="activeEmployeeList" value="#{employeeController.activeEmployees}" var="emp"   itemValue = "#{emp}" label="#{emp.contact.firstName}"   />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The contact table allows the first name column and last name column to be empty, since it allows empty strings some of the displayed value on the selectItems are empty.

How can I prevent these empty first name or empty last name to be displayed/rendered?

Comment: At the time when you are creating List or List of SelectItem that time you can check and ignore to add those empty field to add as a record in the list.

Comment: Two solutions,1st the moment you load them from db, use a faces converter for that dropdown, so you return only non empty values.

Answer (score 0):

Like @subodh-joshi said, you can filter in the `getActiveEmployees` method of `EmployeeController` the employees without first or last name:

```
public List<Employee> getActiveEmployees() {
    List<Employee> employees = ... // get the active employees list
    List<Employee> validEmployees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    for (Employee employee : employees) {
        if ((employee.getFirstName() != null && !employee.getFirstName().trim().isEmpty()) && (employee.getLastName() != null && !employee.getLastName().trim().isEmpty())) {
            validEmployees.add(employee);
        }
    }

    return validEmployees;
}
```

Or better than that, you can return a `List<SelectItem>`:

```
public List<SelectItem> getActiveEmployees() {
    List<Employee> employees = ... // get the active employees list
    List<SelectItem> validEmployees = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

    for (Employee employee : employees) {
        if ((employee.getFirstName() != null && !employee.getFirstName().trim().isEmpty()) && (employee.getLastName() != null && !employee.getLastName().trim().isEmpty())) {
            validEmployees.add(new SelectItem(employee, employee.getContact.getFirstName()));
        }
    }

    return validEmployees;
}
```

Returning a `List` of `SelectItem` there is no need to use `itemValue` and `itemLabel` attributes of `f:selectItems`.